# Pylon.bot MC Status SubCommand TypeError: res.text is not a function

Tags: javascript, typescript

I'm trying to get a minecraft server status command for `Pylon.bot` to work but it keeps throwing the following error:

```
TypeError: res.text is not a function
    at Command.commandHandler (script-157336239102496768.js:321:36)
    at discord.js:2707:34
    at async checkFilterAndExecute (discord.js:2304:11)
    at async checkFilterAndExecute (discord.js:2304:11)
    at async CommandGroup.applyFiltersAndExecute (discord.js:2399:15)
    at async CommandGroup.execute (discord.js:2395:15)
    at async checkFilterAndExecute (discord.js:2304:11)
    at async CommandGroup.applyFiltersAndExecute (discord.js:2399:15)
    at async CommandGroup.execute (discord.js:2395:15)
    at async CommandGroup.handleMessage (discord.js:2363:15)
```

Here is my code:

````
const cmd = new discord.command.CommandGroup({
  defaultPrefix: '!'
});


cmd.subcommand(
  {
    name: 'mc',
    description: 'Minecraft sub commands',
    filters: filters: discord.command.filters.canSendMessages()
  },
  (subcmd) => {
    subcmd.on(
      {
        name: 'status',
        description: 'Get the status of a specified minecraft server',
        filters: filters: discord.command.filters.canSendMessages()    
      },
      (args) => ({
        input: args.text()
      }),
      async (message, { text }) => {
        let res = fetch(`https://api.mcsrvstat.us/2/${text}`);
 
        const data = await res.text();
 
        await message.reply('Response:```' + data + '```');
      }
    );
  }
);
````

Anyone know how to get this working properly? Any help would be more than appreciated.

Comment: Maybe `const data = await (await res).text();`. See [Using Fetch](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch).

Comment: hmm it ran but returned: Response:
```[object Promise]```

Comment: You used the two `await`?

Comment: yeah. I think it needs to be parsed as a json or something. I'm trying to figure that out rn

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe it's supposed to be written like this:

````js
      async (message, { text }) => {
        // `fetch()` returns a promise so will need `await`
        const res = await fetch(`https://api.mcsrvstat.us/2/${text}`);
 
        // `.text()` returns a promise so will also need an `await`
        const data = await res.text();
 
        // `.reply()` returns a promise but we don't need an `await` here
        // because we don't care about the results
        message.reply('Response:```' + data + '```');
      }
````